# Why overrided Paint procedure calls itself again and again when I use Canvas?

Tags: delphi

I had this problem when I was developing my own component from this class: `TImage`
And I used this code:

```
procedure Paint;override;
begin
inherited
canvas.TextOut(5,5,'Hi')
end;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Because the TImage is descendant of TGraphicControl and the procedure Paint is handled inside
WMPaint (windows WM_PAINT) message. So when you paint (inside paint procedure) to the TImage canvas the windows send WM_PAINT message and Paint is called again.

EDIT:
One way to do this is...

```
procedure TMyImage.Paint;
const
  Text = 'Hi';
begin
  inherited;
  Windows.ExtTextOut(Canvas.Handle, 5, 5, 0, nil, PChar(Text), Length(Text), nil);
end;
```

Because Windows.ExtTextOut is API call and will not send WM_PAINT message like...

```
canvas.TextOut(5,5,'Hi')
```

...which internaly call FreeImage procedure.

Comment: Where does `TextOut` call `FreeImage`?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: TCanvas.TextOut call TCanvas.Changing. TCanvas.Changing call event OnChanging. Event OnChanging is set to TBitmap.Changing. First line in TBitmap.Changing call FreeImage.

Answer (score 3):

When you paint to a `TImage`, you're really painting to the underlying `TPicture` object that it displays. If the `Picture` property isn't yet assigned, then the control will allocate a new `TBitmap` for itself so you can draw on that instead. But when it assigns its own `Picture` property, that triggers it to repaint itself.

`TImage` isn't really designed to draw on itself the way you're doing it. You're going to *deface* whatever graphic your users assign, which usually isn't what people expect from a `TImage`. If you want to draw an *overlay* for the `TImage` without modifying the contained graphic, then you should **draw to `inherited Canvas` instead of just `Canvas`**.

Or, if you don't really want to display a user's graphic and just want something to paint on, then plain old `TGraphicControl` is probably the better base class. Or you might not even need a custom control at all. Just put a `TPaintBox` on your form and put your drawing commands in its `OnPaint` event.

Answer (score 2):

You should select TGraphicControl (or TCustomControl) as the parent of your own component to override Paint method properly.

Comment: Not necessary. Even in overriden Paint procedure you can do this right (paint text), but this is another question.